# Solving non-linear system of equations using substitution

Tags: equation-solving

I have 2 equations, `p4a` and `r4p` which relate $a,p,r$ and want to see 6 equations relating all ordered pairs of these 3 variables. Below is an example of doing semi-manually by using `Eliminate` combined with `Solve`. This approach feels like I'm re-implementing built-in functionality (why was manual `Eliminate` step necessary here?), is there a simpler way?

```
p4a = 1/(1 - a);
r4p = 1/(-1 + p);


temp = Eliminate[{p == p4a, r == r4p}, p];
a4r = First@SolveValues[temp, a];
solve[eq_, var_] := Print[var, "=", First@SolveValues[eq, var]];
solve[p == p4a, p]
solve[r == r4p, r]
solve[a == a4r, a]
solve[p == p4a, a]
solve[r == r4p, p]
solve[a == a4r, r]
```

Comment: Yes, just solve for the three possible pairs. `In[331]:= SolveValues[{p == p4a, r == r4p}, {p, r}]

Out[331]= {{1/(1 - a), (1 - a)/a}}

In[332]:= SolveValues[{p == p4a, r == r4p}, {p, a}]

Out[332]= {{(1 + r)/r, 1/(1 + r)}}

In[333]:= SolveValues[{p == p4a, r == r4p}, {r, a}]

Out[333]= {{1/(-1 + p), (-1 + p)/p}}`

Comment: Ahh, so I need to specify all unknowns as "vars", not just the variable I'm solving for

Comment: No, just the ones you are solving for in this case. There are three pairs, so call `SolveValues` three different ways.

Comment: If I try to solve for a single variable, Solve returns no solutions, so I must specify variables in pairs, that's what confused me

Comment: Generally speaking, `n` equations requires `n` variables. Fewer variables than that and it is often generically overdetermined. Empty solution set, unless you give nondefault `MaxExtraConditions`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, I should list all unknown variables as part of `Solve` "vars" parameter, not just the ones I'm trying to solve for